# Is it possible to define a jax-rs service interface separated from its implementation (with eclipse and jersey)?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I don't know if the title is confusing, but let's say I have this interface:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user")
public interface UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId);

}
```

Why when I try to implement a version Eclipse rewrites annotation for the overridden method but not for the class?

```
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I was trying to create a standard definition for the restful web service and then having different implementations. Is something like this possible with standard jax-rs? Am I using wrong annotations by any chance?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use annotation inheritance only if you don't use *any* `jax-rs` annotation on the implementing class: it is stated on section 3.6 of JSR-339.

You redefine  `@Path` and `@Produces` for the method but not for the class.

So the `Path` annotation in your code should be on the concrete class:

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId);

}


@Path("/user")
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

BTW, the specification encourages us to replicate the annotations on the concrete classes:

> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended to always repeat annotations instead
>   of relying on annotation inheritance.

Comment: you actually do not need to put the annotations both on interface and the concrete. you can just put all on the interface except for the @Path on the class (@Path("/user")).

Comment: i meant that you can leave it on the interface no the concrete. this way you can make the interface available for a client proxy.

Comment: @shlomi33 You are right, but it is not an encouraged practice. Maybe after the last edit it is better stated.

Comment: I have found that if I add POST and PathParam on interface method but not on implementing class method, I get 404. (Using jersey, grizzly).

Comment: The quote mentioned in this answer can be found in 3.6 Annotation Inheritance in this doc(pdf): http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-edr2-spec/jaxrs-2_0-edr2-spec.pdf

Comment: @CarloPellegrini Your recommendation of writing the annotations on both the interface and implementation classes violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). I am curious as to where your recommendation comes from. Could you provide a source?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue working with interface automatically generated using the OpenAPI generator. The problem here was that I couldn't easily remove the `@Path` annotation from the interface and additionally adding it to the class caused ambiguity issues.

Problems with `@Path`-annotated interfaces however only occurs for resources that are automatically discovered on registered packages. For registered packages, all classes (and unfortunately interfaces as well) that are annotated with `@Path` will be instantiated.

To prevent that, you can just register your resources manually with your `ResourceConfig` as in the following example:

```
new ResourceConfig()
    .registerClasses(UserServiceImpl.class);
```

Just make sure, your interfaces are not in a package that are registered with your `ResourceConfig`. Using this approach, you can use the implementation from your example and also the `@Path` annotation added to the interface will be interpreted correctly.

Disclaimer: There probably should not be any `@Path` path annotation on the interface in the first place, but unfortunately this is what the OpenAPI generator creates. If you find yourself in a similar situation, I hope this helps. Otherwise, you should refer to the accepted answer.