# JAX-RS + Spring

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs

I am learning Spring and trying make simple SOA project and I have simple test class:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayhello() { return "hello"};
}
```

But I want interface for JAX-RS and some autoinjected implementation:

```
@Path("/hello")
public interface HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    String sayhello();
}

public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorldResource {
    @Override
    public String sayhello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And I know that in Java EE I can do it with one annotation (@Stateless for example) 
But how can I do the same with Spring 4+?

Comment: It is not about Spring.
[answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950873/is-it-possibile-to-define-a-jax-rs-service-interface-separated-from-its-implemen

Answer (score 1):

This post makes a few assumptions:

1. I assume you have set up resource discovery, IE your servlet is correctly routing `/hello` to the `HelloWorldResource`.
   If this doesn't make any sense to you, you'll want to look into registering Jax-RS resources with your servlet container.
2. I assume you have set up a Spring context by registering a `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` in your web.xml.

You will need to mark your `HelloWorldImpl` to be discovered by spring. The easiest way to do that is to enable annotation-processing in your spring context.xml (loaded by passing it as `contextConfigLocation` to your `ContextLoaderListener`).

Then it should be sufficient to mark `HelloWorldImpl` with a `@Controller` and declare it as a `bean` in your context.xml.