# Contract First OpenAPI Generation

Tags: open-liberty, openapi-generator

I tried to use a simple OpenAPI V3 API for implementing on OpenLiberty with a contract-first paradigm.

I use the following plugin for OpenAPI Code generation:

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

For generation I use `<generatorName>jaxrs-spec</generatorName>`

As `<configOptions>` I use `<useSwaggerAnnotations>false</useSwaggerAnnotations>`

Beside the model classes the following Interface is generated:

```
@Path("/inventory")
public interface InventoryApi {

  @GET
  @Path("/systems/{hostname}")
  @Produces({ "text/plain", "application/json" })
  Response getPropertiesForHost(@PathParam("hostname") String hostname);

  @GET
  @Path("/systems")
  @Produces({ "application/json" })
  Response listContents();
}
```

I try to use my Implementation as lean as possible like this:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/")
public class InventoryImpl implements InventoryApi {

   public Response getPropertiesForHost(String hostname) {
      ...
   }

   public Response listContents() {
      ...
   }    
}
```

I can call with the following curl command
`curl -X GET "http://localhost:9080/properties-sample/systems"`
This works!

But I would have expected to use the following
`curl -X GET "http://localhost:9080/properties-sample/inventory/systems"`
But this does not work.
I have to change the @Path in the Impl to `@Path("/inventory")`, so it works using `curl -X GET "http://localhost:9080/properties-sample/inventory/systems"`

Is this working as designed or are `@Path` Annotations on the interface irrelevant?

Does somebody else has another way of using contract first paradigm with OpenLiberty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct to use the OpenAPI Tools plugin for this.  Open Liberty supports [MicroProfile OpenAPI](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api), which allows you to expose your contract-first OAS3 doc, but for generation purposes Open Liberty defers to the OSS OpenAPI Tools community.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956510) should help guide your interface vs implementing class decisions with regards to the JAX-RS annotations.  In particular, in your example you are overriding the main @Path annotation, hence the different behaviour.